# GridLayout not resizing to fit components

Tags: java, swing, layout, grid-layout

The grid layout has two columns and is giving 50% space to each side, no matter what size the components actually are. SetPrefferedSize doesn't seem to work either - but I shouldn't need it, this shold be done automatically, right?

[image]

Can I make the first row's width to resize to fit "SomeOtherLongText3:"?

SSCCE:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel();
        detailsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 15, 0));

        // Add to left side (WEST)
        frame.add(detailsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        // Add some labels:
        detailsPanel.add(getLabel("Some text:"));
        detailsPanel.add(new JLabel("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc id mauris "));


        detailsPanel.add(getLabel("Some text 2:"));
        detailsPanel.add(new JLabel("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc id mauris "));

        detailsPanel.add(getLabel("Some other text 3:"));
        detailsPanel.add(new JLabel("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc id mauris "));

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(900, 100));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static JLabel getLabel(String text)
    {
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(text);
        lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        return lbl;
    }

}
```

Also, another problem is that you can just re-size the window to cut the text:
[image]

Comment: I am not clear on the requirement here.  Could you amend your SSCCE to show at least the first 2 lines of the 'like such'?  What does the `WEST` constraint have to do with it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson OK I will. I have to add something else to the right, this is part of a bigger program - that explains the WEST.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Edited. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Layout Strategies

1. Put 2 single column `GridLayout` instances in the `WEST` (labels) and `CENTER` (values) of a `BorderLayout`.  Add the outer panel to the `WEST` or the parent..
2. Use a `GroupLayout`.  That might be better since you can use HTML/CSS to limit the width of the values and force them to multiple lines.